# Missing current_page_item in custom menu

Tags: customization, menus

I'm using the new custom menus in my side navigation and it only creates a class sub-menu in the `UL's` but does not use the `current_page_item` like when you use `wp_list_pages()`. I have 3 levels and only want to show the sub menus of the page you are on, easily done using `wp_list_pages()` but I can't do it with the custom menus?

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The current-item CSS class generated by `wp_nav_menu()` is `.current-menu-item`. However, `wp_nav_menu()` also has backward-compatibility with `wp_page_menu()`/`wp_list_pages()`, and *does* output `.current_page_item` (if the current context is a `page` post-type, of course).

So, a couple of possibilities:

1. The current context is *not* a static Page
2. You're using a custom walker for the `wp_nav_menu()` output, that doesn't output a CSS class for `.current*`.